# How to add "return" to SPSS syntax?

Tags: spss

I have written the following SPSS syntax for an OLS. For me, this is easy to read. Different variables are grouped in one line and a comment describes what they are:

```
/* model (3d) hbs returns IV, lag DV, IV lag 1 and 2
REGRESSION 
  /MISSING LISTWISE 
  /STATISTICS COEFF OUTS R ANOVA 
  /CRITERIA=PIN(.05) POUT(.10) 
  /NOORIGIN 
  /DEPENDENT retExc0
  /METHOD=ENTER 
  hbsVol0LN hbsBullQuality0 hbsAgreeQuality0 wiki0LN svi0 /* independent
  retExc1 retExc2 /* lag dependent
  hbsVol1LN hbsBullQuality1 hbsAgreeQuality1 Wiki1LN svi1 /* lag 1 independent
  hbsVol2LN hbsBullQuality2 hbsAgreeQuality2 Wiki2LN svi2 /* lag 2 independent
  secEnergy secMat secIndus secConsS secHealth secFin secIT secTelco secUtil /* control
  dayMon dayTue dayWed dayFri /* control
  news
  marketRet0 
  day01 day02 day03 day04 day05 day06 day07 day08 day09 day10 day11 day12 day13 day14 day15 day16 day17 day18 day19 day20 day21 day22 day23 day24 day25 day26 day27 day28 day29 day30 day31
  /RESIDUALS DURBIN.
```

This is, however, not accepted by the syntax interpreter, which expects all variables to follow directly after the regression `/MEHOD`:

```
/* model (3d) hbs returns IV, lag DV, IV lag 1 and 2
REGRESSION 
  /MISSING LISTWISE 
  /STATISTICS COEFF OUTS R ANOVA 
  /CRITERIA=PIN(.05) POUT(.10) 
  /NOORIGIN 
  /DEPENDENT retExc0
  /METHOD=ENTER hbsVol0LN hbsBullQuality0 hbsAgreeQuality0 wiki0LN svi0 retExc1 retExc2 hbsVol1LN hbsBullQuality1 hbsAgreeQuality1 Wiki1LN svi1 hbsVol2LN hbsBullQuality2 hbsAgreeQuality2 Wiki2LN svi2 secEnergy secMat secIndus secConsS secHealth secFin secIT secTelco secUtil dayMon dayTue dayWed dayFri news marketRet0 day01 day02 day03 day04 day05 day06 day07 day08 day09 day10 day11 day12 day13 day14 day15 day16 day17 day18 day19 day20 day21 day22 day23 day24 day25 day26 day27 day28 day29 day30 day31
  /RESIDUALS DURBIN.
```

This, however, doesn't look very easy to maintain. How can I concatenate the lines of variables so that the interpreter accepts my original input, for instance something like:

```
/* model (3d) hbs returns IV, lag DV, IV lag 1 and 2
REGRESSION 
  /MISSING LISTWISE 
  /STATISTICS COEFF OUTS R ANOVA 
  /CRITERIA=PIN(.05) POUT(.10) 
  /NOORIGIN 
  /DEPENDENT retExc0
  /METHOD=ENTER ;
  hbsVol0LN hbsBullQuality0 hbsAgreeQuality0 wiki0LN svi0 ;
  retExc1 retExc2 ;
  hbsVol1LN hbsBullQuality1 hbsAgreeQuality1 Wiki1LN svi1 ;
  hbsVol2LN hbsBullQuality2 hbsAgreeQuality2 Wiki2LN svi2 ;
  secEnergy secMat secIndus secConsS secHealth secFin secIT secTelco secUtil ;
  dayMon dayTue dayWed dayFri ;
  news ;
  marketRet0 ;
  day01 day02 day03 day04 day05 day06 day07 day08 day09 day10 day11 day12 day13 day14 day15 day16 day17 day18 day19 day20 day21 day22 day23 day24 day25 day26 day27 day28 day29 day30 day31
  /RESIDUALS DURBIN.
```

Is something like this possible and if so, how?

Answer (score 1):

I did not encounter any errors with the following syntax structurally identical to yours. It worked correctly.

```
/* model (3d) hbs returns IV, lag DV, IV lag 1 and 2.
REGRESSION 
  /MISSING LISTWISE 
  /STATISTICS COEFF OUTS R ANOVA 
  /CRITERIA=PIN(.05) POUT(.10) 
  /NOORIGIN 
  /DEPENDENT y
  /METHOD=ENTER 
  x1 x2 x3 /* independent
  x4 x5 /* lag dependent
  x6 x7 x8 x9 /* lag 1 independent
  x10 x11 x12 x13 /* lag 2 independent
  x14 x15 x16 /* control
  x17 x18 x19 /* control
  x20
  x21 
  x23 x24 x25 x26 x27 x28 x29 x30
  /RESIDUALS DURBIN.
```

Answer (score 1):

Line breaks are perfectly acceptable in Statistics syntax.  It would help if you posted the actual error message you got.  Perhaps there was a nonprinting character on a line that confused thing.

A completely blank line terminates the command, but that seems not to be the case here.

Generally, in interactive mode (which even production syntax usually uses), a command continues until a blank line or a terminating period, and line breaks are irrelevant.  (Multi-line literals take some additional attention.)